# How to add a new item into array in an object that's is in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

Here is my state

```
const initState = [
    {
        id: 1,
        criteria: [],
        isInclusion: true,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        criteria: [],
        isInclusion: true,
    },
];
```

I am trying to add a new object into criteria array with my `dispatch`

```
 dispatch(
            addCriteria({
                id: item.id,
                type: item.type,
                groupId: 1, 
            })
        );
```

in the `reducer` I do the following but it doesnt add to an array of an existing group but instead, it adds as a new object to the array with that criteria added in it.

```
const addReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUERYGROUPS.ADD_CRITERIA: {

            const newCriteria = {
                id: action.payload.id,
                type: action.payload.type,
            }; 
            const newState = [
                ...state,
                state.map(group =>
                    group.id === action.payload.groupId
                        ? {
                              ...group,
                              criteria: newCriteria,
                          }
                        : group
                ),
            ];
            return newState;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding all items to the state object (also the one you want to modify) with ...state and than you map over it again. This will not work.

You should change your state object to be an object to access the items by reference and not index and use the id as access. This will also be faster(thanks @Yash Joshi ):

```
const initState = {
    1: {
        criteria: [],
        isInclusion: true,
    },
    2: {
        criteria: [],
        isInclusion: true,
    },
};
```

This will let you access and update the state more easily and easier to stay immutable.
This will let you update it like this:

```
case QUERYGROUPS.ADD_CRITERIA: {
        const newCriteria = {
            id: action.payload.id,
            type: action.payload.type,
        }; 
        const newState = {
            ...state,
            [action.payload.groupId]: {
                ...state[action.payload.groupId],
                criteria: [
                    ...state[action.payload.groupId].criteria,
                    newCriteria
                ],
            }                
        };
        return newState;
```

To add a new item to it:

```
 const newState = {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.groupId]: {
            isInclusion: false,
            criteria: [ ],
        }                
    };
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Right this will be also faster than the approach @Markov is using.

Comment: I like this and it works but now my question is how would I add a new object to it like a 3 : { criteria:[], inInclusion: true} in an another action such as QUERYGROUPS.ADD_GROUP

Answer (score 0):

Try spread operator (es6):

```
return [
   ...state,
   newCriteria,
]
```

This will return a new array with the `newCriteria` object on it.

Comment: I don't think this would work in his case. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g28opyfe/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it:

```js
const newCriteria = {
    id: action.payload.id,
    type: action.payload.type,
};

const newState = state.map(gr => {
    if (gr.id !== action.payload.groupId) {
        return gr;
    }

    return {
        ...gr,
        criteria: [...gr.criteria, newCriteria];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow Domino987 approach it will be faster. But if you still wish to continue with your approach. You can try this:

```
const newState = state.map(item => item.id === newItem.id ? ({ ...item, ...newItem }) : item );

return newState;
```

Hope this Helps!